# Generating connection string in web.config while loading dll in application

Tags: c#, asp.net, class-library

I have written a class library file and use the dll of this file in web application

i write some code in this dll like generating connection string as well as appSettings in web.config file

but problem is that.... i want to generate this connection string and appsettings data while adding this dll in web application instead of running the application

so plz help me....

i think some frnz are not understand my question
i elaborate more below..

when i add dll in my application it added successfully
no problem about it.
when i run my application then connection string generate in web.config

bt what happen with this...
all sessions are cleared

hence i want to generate this connection string at the time of adding this dll in application

so is there any event handler or loader is available which will help to get me result

Comment: Please read [FAQ] and [ask] a couple of times..

Comment: @Dan Is there a chance you have Stack Overflow confused with some other place that doesn't have a [FAQ specifying that rudeness is unacceptable](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette)?  That's no way to treat people on this site, especially brand new users.  Besides that, you have edit privileges - if it bugs you so much, edit the question, and leave a *constructive* comment explaining why one should use proper spelling and grammar on a professional website.

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question correctly then 
You need to add that Class Library as a reference in your web application.
Just right click on the solution > Add reference > Browse to the Class Library and add it to the project.
Then you can use your class library in you web application.

Hope it helps...

Comment: I think u r not understand my question

i elaborate more below...

when i add dll in my application it added successfully
no problem about it.
when i run my application then connection string generate in web.config

bt what happen with this...
all sessions are cleared 

hence i want to generate this connection string at the time of adding this dll in application

so is there any event handler or loader is available which will help to get me result